# Filter array objects based on uniqueness of one property

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

The situation that I'm dealing with is that I have an array of objects and I would like to filter down to an array where the objects are unique with regard to one property keeping the last instance.

For example lets say I have an array of files like so:

```
let files = 
     [
        {
          filename: "filename.txt",
          uploadedBy: "Bob",
          comment: "Gee whiz"
        },
          filename: "filename.txt",
          uploadedBy: "Jane",
          comment: "Golly"
        },
          filename: "otherFile.txt",
          uploadedBy: "Bob",
          comment: "Shucks"
        },
          filename: "filename.txt",
          uploadedBy: "Henry",
          comment: "Gee Willikers"
        },
     ]
```

I want the objects with distinct filenames and I want the last instance of each filename.

```
     [
          filename: "otherFile.txt",
          uploadedBy: "Bob",
          comment: "Shucks"
        },
          filename: "filename.txt",
          uploadedBy: "Henry",
          comment: "Gee Willikers"
        },
     ]
```

Is there a concise way of doing this? All I can come up with is a pretty long method to first `map` the array to get just the filenames, then find the last instance of each filename or something.

The following question is similar but keeps the first value not the last :
[Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

```
 function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

// usage example:
var a = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
var unique = a.filter( onlyUnique ); // returns ['a', 1, 2, '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first get only unique file names from the array, then simply map over them and look for the first element in the reversed files array.

```js
const f = [{"filename":"filename.txt","uploadedBy":"Bob","comment":"Gee whiz"},{"filename":"filename.txt","uploadedBy":"Jane","comment":"Golly"},{"filename":"otherFile.txt","uploadedBy":"Bob","comment":"Shucks"},{"filename":"filename.txt","uploadedBy":"Henry","comment":"Gee Willikers"}].reverse();

const unique = [...new Set(f.map(({ filename }) => filename))]
         .map((name) => f.find(({ filename }) => filename === name)); 

console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce to a Map, and use the `filename` as the key to set the item, and then spread the `Map.values()` iterator back to an array:

```js
const files = [{"filename":"filename.txt","uploadedBy":"Bob","comment":"Gee whiz"},{"filename":"filename.txt","uploadedBy":"Jane","comment":"Golly"},{"filename":"otherFile.txt","uploadedBy":"Bob","comment":"Shucks"},{"filename":"filename.txt","uploadedBy":"Henry","comment":"Gee Willikers"}]

const result = [...
  files.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.filename, o), new Map())
.values()]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Map`](https://www.google.com/search?q=map%20mdn&oq=map%20m&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0j69i60l3.1314j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which has each unique `filename` as key and the the file object as value. If another entry with the same `filename` is found, it will overwrite the previous value. So, it will always be the last occurrence. Then get the [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) of the Map to just the file objects

```js
const files=[{filename:"filename.txt",uploadedBy:"Bob",comment:"Gee whiz"},{filename:"filename.txt",uploadedBy:"Jane",comment:"Golly"},{filename:"otherFile.txt",uploadedBy:"Bob",comment:"Shucks"},{filename:"filename.txt",uploadedBy:"Henry",comment:"Gee Willikers"},];

const map = new Map(files.map(f => [f.filename, f])),
      unique = Array.from(map.values());
      
console.log(unique)
```